# ORA-12505 TNS:listener could not resolve SID diven in connect descriptor

Tags: java, oracle

Здравствуйте, возникает такая ошибка при подключении к удаленной БД Oracle. Но подключение осуществляется к серверу установленному на локальной машине. Нужно организовать подключение к удаленной БД. Может ли возникать такая ошибка из-за неправильного выбора драйвера. И какой драйвер подключить?
Мой драйвер, который я подключаю:
`Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема не связана с драйвером. Эта ошибка возникает когда SID указанный в связи не был найден.

Почитать про эту ошибку вы можете [тут](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2FGUID.571F6E84.1EE2.4F68.80C7.B1DC863536CB%2FID0925GN00WYK.html)

Comment: спасибо.
а еще такой вопрос: от типа подключения к БД не зависит?
Я просто запрашиваю у пользователя всю нужную для работы моего приложения информацию и подключаюсь к БД
`public final DataBaseTableModel dbtm;
dbtm = new DataBaseTableModel( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + host + ":" + port + ":" + serviceName + "", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", user, passwd);`

Comment: может ли такое возникать, когда я подключаюсь к БД с помощью SID'a , а не ServiceName?

Comment: Подключение с помощью ServiceName будет таким:
`jdbc:oracle:thin:@//HOSTNAME:PORT/SERVICENAME`