# ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: sql, oracle

Пытаюсь создать connection в SQL Developer. Возникает такая ошибка ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app

tnsnames.ora

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

SYSDBA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = sysdba)
    )
  )

LISTENER_SYSDBA =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
```

Comment: напиши что находится в listener.ora на сервере и tnsnames.ora на клиенте. Проблема в SID понятно дело

Comment: На форуме уже был такой [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468318/ora-12505-tnslistener-could-not-resolve-sid-diven-in-connect-descriptor). Надеюсь он поможет.

Comment: К сожалению, не помог.

Comment: А в девелопере вы какое имя сервера вбиваете ? Вот в SYSDBA указан некий serive_name. вместо него стоит написать SID. последние строчки вообще странные. то что LISTENER_SYSDBA

Comment: В поле имя сервера ничего не пишу. Поменяла на SID , не помогло.

Comment: Как ничего ... вот он ничего и ищет в файле. попробуйте написать SYSDBA раз так сервис назвали

Comment: тогда выдает ошибку ora 01017 invalid username/password logon denied, хотя ввела правильно

Comment: Ну эта ошибка по крайней мере означает что связь с сервером установилась. А вот пользователя неприняла, например потому что не указали SYSDBA в поле роли подключаемого для системного пользователя. А первая ошибка - что сервер вообще не найден. так что решайте вторую проблему.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Надо ознакомится с более детальным описанием причин и действий в случае этой ошибки:

```
$ oerr ora 12505
12505, 00000, "TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor"
// *Cause:  The listener received a request to establish a connection to a
// database or other service. The connect descriptor received by the listener
// specified a SID for an instance (usually a database instance) that either
// has not yet dynamically registered with the listener or has not been
// statically configured for the listener. This may be a temporary condition
// such as after the listener has started, but before the database instance
// has registered with the listener.
// *Action:
//  - Wait a moment and try to connect a second time.
//  - Check which instances are currently known by the listener by executing:
//    lsnrctl services <listener name>
//  - Check that the SID parameter in the connect descriptor specifies
//    an instance known by the listener.
//  - Check for an event in the listener.log file.
```

Листенер получил запрос на подключение, но указанный идентификатор соединения ему неизвестен. Например, если он получит следующий параметр, то об идентификаторе `ХХХ` он первый раз слышит:

```
[...]
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = ХХХ))
```

Как идентификатор соединения могут быть указаны:

- *SERVICE_NAME* - сотоящий из `DB_NAME` - имя БД, которое было задано при установке и `DOMAIN_NAME` - по умолчанию домен сервера БД, например, _mydomain.ru.
- *SID* - системный идентификатор инстанции БД, для разработчиков он не релевантен и не должен использоваться, должен быть прописан в конфигурации listener.ora, служит для удалённого администрирования инстанции БД

Узнать, что листенеру уже известно, можно командой `lsnrctl status` (с опцией `services`, более подробно). Если в выводе нет строк с искомым именем сервиса, то он неверный:

```
Service "ХХХ" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORACL", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

В итоге, следующий запрос на подключение из вопроса, удался бы:

```
sqlplus sys/<pass>@localhost/sysdba as sysdba
```

---

PS  выбор имени сервиса сделанный ТС, не совсем удачен и может вызвать непонимание